# Is Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorService thread-safe?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

About the Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.Actor, I know it single-threaded execution from the document ["An actor is an isolated, independent unit of compute and state with single-threaded execution. "](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction).

Is Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Runtime.ActorService thread-safe? There are few document about it. We used it in our application, It seems not thread-safe in multi-nodes and multi-instance. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reliable Actors are packaged in Reliable Services (`ActorService`) that can be deployed in the Service Fabric infrastructure. Actor instances are activated in a named service instance.

`ActorService` is just a Stateful Service. Services allow concurrent access.

**edit:removed wrong remark about StateManager**

What issues are you seeing?

Comment: thanks for your information, I will use transactions in my problem.

Comment: The ActorService inherit from StatefulServiceBase and don't have StateManager to create transaction. the StatefulService also inherit from StatefulServiceBase, so ActorService and StatefulService  are same level.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. What issues are you getting?

Comment: I used StatefulService  StateManager  implement, it seems solved my problem. 
My problem is I use ActorService to read EventSoruce read model, that have some strange problem which I guess caused by ActorService is not thread-safe.